# Flutter - A RenderFlex overflowed by 2.4 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, I have a code which displays the related products and the products seen in my product_page.dart view. Only when displayed I have the yellow banner - A RenderFlex overflowed by 2.4 pixels on the bottom.
Here is the relevant part on my product_page.dart

```
      `         const RelatedProductsWidget(),
                16.verticalSpace,
                ViewedProductsWidgetInProductDetails(
                  onSeeAllPressed: () =>
                      context.pushRoute( ViewedProductsRoute()),
                  isLoading: state.isViewedProductsLoading,
                  products: state.viewedProducts,
                  onLiked: notifier.likeOrUnlikeProduct,
                ),
                86.verticalSpace,`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlfOV.png)

Thank you